# redirect using htaccess, if a url contains query string

Tags: wordpress, htaccess

I want to do permanent redirect using htaccess. For eg :- I want to redirect `/modules/pages/?pageid=7` to `http://www.xxx.com/aaa/`.

This is what i have done `Redirect permanent /modules/pages/?pageid=7 http://www.xxx.com/aaa/`
but it gives me 404 error.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in you .htaccess, placing this above your wordpress rules (just under `RewriteEngine On`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^pageid=7$
RewriteRule ^modules/pages/$ http://www.xxx.com/aaa/ [R=301,L]
```

Mod_alias's `Redirect` won't match against query strings.